# Передача данных в exec

Tags: php, exec

Как правильно через exec() передать аргументы в скрипт, и как в скрипте их получить? По мануалу не понял.

```
exec("php import.php >> import.log 2>&1 &", $data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [мануал](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php), что именно непонятно?

Comment: А как в скрипте их принять? Передаю я массив $data, как принять его в скрипте?

Comment: Точно так же, как и для любой другой программы: 

    script.php argument1 argument2 ...

Ну или:

    exec("script.php $data[0] $data[1] $data[2] ...")

Или:

    exec("script.php ".base64_encode(json_encode($data)))

Или...

Никаких "массивов $data" здесь уже не существует, скрипт в этом контексте рассматривается как обычное приложение. Как принять в скрипте - написано в мануале.

Comment: Ааааа, т.е. в скрипте переменная $argv и будет переменными. Понял. Спасибо :)

Comment: Для тех, кто будет в будущем смотреть. Используйте  base64_encode(json_encode($data)). Так как сточные значения могут быть восприняты не так.